# Installed ubuntu from USB but it won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I have just installed ubuntu. When I turn on my computer is says "no bootable device." When I boot my computer with my USB drive plugged in, it boots to a "grub>" prompt. How can I get my computer to boot to ubuntu off of my HD?

Comment: what mode are you booting in?  Legacy or EFI ?

Comment: I installed 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: in which boot mode? I assume you erased the whole drive

Comment: I don't know the difference. I have altered my boot priorities from USB to HD in the bios. But it will only boot from USB. I don't know how to find out what my boot mode is.

Comment: is the computer 64 bit? during the install did you mark a partition as ESP?

Comment: i chose to remove my previous operating system and install ubuntu in its place. I didn't alter or create any partitions during the install.

Comment: It is a brand new acer aspire notebook. I assume it is 64 bit.

Comment: during the install all partitions were created. boot from the usb and use gparted to look at the drive structure

Comment: yes, likely 64-bit efi, you turned secure boot off?

Comment: 3 partitions. 1 has fat32 file system, 2 has ext4, 3 has linux-swap

Comment: i think i chose to require password for boot

Comment: yes  it is efi. you aren't making it that far... turn off the efi boot flag on the fat partition with gparted so we can look in the partition

Comment: boot flag is unchecked

Comment: open the partition in the file manager. there should be a folder named /EFI/. inside that should be /ubuntu and /boot.

Comment: i don't see an EFI folder anywhere.

Comment: found a boot folder there is an eft folder inside that as well as a grub folder

Comment: you opened the fat partition on the HD yes? that is the error. grub didn't install?  look in the ext4 partition for vmlinuz and initrd.img the they there? give me  a couple minutes to write an answer.

Comment: i see both of those files on my home directory

Comment: i guess its my root directory no home

Answer (score -1):

you partition scheme looks like EFI mode active. to be sure you can shut off legacy mode in system settings;

Boot from the USB and in grub type "c" to get a command prompt

type:

> linux (hd1,2)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
>   initrd (hd1,2)/initrd.img
>   boot

if you get initramfs rescue mode -- enter your password then startx
you should now have a desktop.

Open a terminal and type:
`sudo install-grub`
`sudo update-grub`
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

reboot and see what you get

EDITS: changes to reflect your particular hardware setup

Comment: says disk hd0,2 not found

Comment: type ls (that is an L)

Comment: secure boot forbids loading module from hd0.......

Comment: ok need to turn secure boot off in the system settings(what used to be BIOS) and looks like the USB is narked as hd0 ... so do as I marked the changes

Comment: it only allows me to take of secure boot if i change to legacy

Comment: i booted in legacy then booted from HD from the menu there

Comment: try as I have edited the answer. I need to go. since ubuntu is the only system a legacy install is a valid option also

Comment: i now have a command prompt (initramfs)

Comment: asking for password? or kernel panic?

Comment: nope. looks like a built-in shell (ash)

Comment: ack computers, appears the drive was reassigned during boot. make the first line `linux (hd1,2)/vmlinux root=/dev/sda2  if that doesn't work I'll be back in an hour

Comment: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ") ")

Comment: try again, you typed it wrong